# Get the pre-last element of a string split by spaces

Tags: c#

Input examples:

```
7 9 12 16 18 21 25 27 30 34 36 39 43 45 48 52 54 57 61
```

```
7 9 12 16 18 21 25 27 30 34 36 39 43 45 48 52 54 57 ... 75 79
```

Note that it ends with a space.

I want to get 57 in the first case and 75 in the second case as integer. I tried with the following:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Shorten(sequence).Split(' ').ElementAt(sequence.Length - 2));
```

The problem is that `sequence.Length` is not really the right index.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core 3 by any chance?

Comment: Before you split the string, remove the trailing space. That should give you the expected index. Otherwise if youe using Core 3.0 you can use `Span<T>` and then use [1^] to get the 2nd from last index.

Comment: or use stringsplitoptions.removeemptyentries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the overload for `Split()` and pass the `RemoveEmptyEntires` enum:

```
string input = "7 9 12 16 18 21 25 27 30 34 36 39 43 45 48 52 54 57 61 ";
var splitInput = input.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var inputInt = Convert.ToInt32(splitInput[splitInput.Length - 2]);
// inputInt is 57
```

Doing it this way allows your last element to *actually* be what you want.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/35cm2k)

Comment: On a side note, since dealing with strings, I would make sure you can actually convert that to an integer; cant trust them. So something like `var inputInt = int.TryParse(splitInput[splitInput.Length - 2].ToString(), out int myInt) ? myInt : 0?`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I disagree. He expects an integer. Anything else is bad input and **should** break. Defaulting to `0` could have unintended consequences.

Comment: @JuanR depends on how the op is using `inputInt` and how the op is checking this field, otherwise you could still throw... My example isn't concrete, OP could do what they choose, it's a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Based on maccettura's answer, in C# 8 you can simplify index acces like so

```
var input = "1 2 3";
var parts = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var value = parts.Length >= 2 ? Convert.ToInt32(parts[^2]) : null;
```

Comment: I think `Count` should be `Length` right?  The return type of `Split()` is an array...

Comment: Thanks for that! @maccettura, yea it is `string[]`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not another answer.

Comment: @JuanR `should be a comment` and based on what exactly? The poster included an alternative solution with code. Why would they put this in a comment? Do solutions that have code provided belong in the comment section?

Comment: This should be a comment because it's essentially the same code written in a different way. He has acknowledged this himself: "Based on maccettura's answer...". He could have simply made a comment saying "in C# 8 you can simplify index access like so: `parts.Length >= 2 ? Convert.ToInt32(parts[^2]) : null;`

Answer (score 0):

How about something that doesn't use strings at all.

```
public static int? SplitReverseInt(this string str, int ixFromBack)
{
    var inWord = false;
    var wEnd = 0;
    var found = 0;

    for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var charr = str[i];
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(charr))
        {
            // we found the beginning of a word
            if (inWord)
            {
                if (found == ixFromBack)
                {
                    var myInt = 0;
                    for (int j = i+1; j <= wEnd; j++)
                        myInt = (myInt * 10 + str[j] - '0');

                    return myInt;
                }

                inWord = false;
                found++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!inWord)
            {
                wEnd = i;
                inWord = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // word (number) is at the beginning of the string
    if (inWord && found == ixFromBack)
    {
        var myInt = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= wEnd; j++)
            myInt = (myInt * 10 + str[j] - '0');

        return myInt;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Performance is about 10 times faster on the example strings.
This only loops from the back, and only fetches one number, it doesnt create substrings or an array of strings we don't need.

Use like this:

```
var numberFromBack = SplitReverseInt(input, 1);
```